# Intel AMT KVM: Accessing Multiple Servers Behind One Public IP Address

Tags: remote-access, intel, amt

I have to host multiple servers in a collocation center which is distant over 250 km. I need to have as good remote control over the servers as possible. In other words, I need to be able to access BIOS of the servers, be able to turn the servers ON or OFF, or to remotely re-install the Operating System.

For this purpose the relatively fresh Intel vPro AMT KVM technology is just optimal and cost effective. I can access just one server over the public IP address of that server.

What I do not know is, how to access multiple servers via Intel vPro KVM, if they all are behind one Public IP Address. Will technologies like IP Address Translation or Port Forwarding work for me? Could you advise please, how to configure the network so, that I would be able to access any of the servers on the network if of course they all support Intel vPro AMT (and KVM)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set yourself up with a VPN connection to the remote site.

Comment: @googology: Yes, elegant and simple solution. Thank you. I am marking this one as the *"accepted answer"*

Answer (score 0):

You should setup AMT-connection in CIRA-mode which allows to work behind NAT. You will need to do it Intel MPS server.